# Total by group value not included in data

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Imagine the following data, which includes a column "Color". Possible values are Red, Blue and Yellow.

```
Other fields    Color   A  B  C
--------------------------------
   ...          Red     1  3  0
   ...          Red     0  1  6
   ...          Yellow  3  4  5
```

This is shown on a Tablix component. After it, I want to summarize by color, including all possible colors:

```
Color    A  B  C
-----------------
Red      1  4  6
Blue     0  0  0  <-- how to create this row?
Yellow   3  4  5
```

I insert a new Tablix component, group by Color, and hide the Details group, leaving the totals. But of course, that doesn't include colors missing in the data.

How can I do it?

Restrictions to potential solutions:

- I can create another dataset with **just the color names**, if necessary.
- I can't modify the original query (which retrieves A, B and C quantities).
- I can't create a new dataset with a query joining a subquery with the color names and the one which retrieves the quantities. The latter is quite expensive and I'd rather not have the users wait twice the time...
- If VB code is needed, it can only be in the Report Code.

Comment: Does your dataset include the rows for Blue?

Comment: @BishNaboB The dataset doesn't include the rows for Blue, that's why I have trouble including it in the summary.

Comment: But it *could* include them and another color could be missing, depending on the parameters, of course. I don't know exactly which colors are going to be missing when I run the report.

Comment: My preferred method for this would be to generate the colours in the SQL. So generate a list and left join to your actual data so that "Blue" (or whatever colours) are there with nulls for the rest of the columns.

Comment: @BishNaboB Unfortunately I can't do that (I edited the question to make it more clear). The solution needs to be mainly inside the report.

Comment: What exactly is the reason to not do a join to a list of colours?

Comment: @BishNaboB - It's explained. **(a)** I can't modify the original query (it is ran and the resultset is bound to the report by means I don't control); **(b)** if I were to create a new query, duplicating the original, adding a join with the link of colors, the report would take twice as long. It's an expensive query.

Comment: Can we have a look at the original query. I shouldn't have thought that adding a left outer join would cause it to run twice as long...

Comment: In that case the original query would run for the first Tablix and then the modified one for the summary. Can we just forget about that approach? Isn't there a client-side solution?

Comment: @angus the new left joined query would replace the whole query. That way you get a row per colour per result, which can then be aggregated in the tablix to get the summary.  There's not a client side approach unless you do a new query of just colours and do lookups / aggregated lookupsets for each column to get your summary information

Comment: @BishNaboB "do a new query of just colours and do lookups / aggregated lookupsets for each column".  That might be the solution. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can do a query to return a list of all potential colours. Make your tablix link to that dataset, and group by the colour column. You can then do a lookupset() along the lines of `lookupset(Colour, Colour, ThingToSummarise, "Dataset")`. This will return an array/object of all the rows where the colours match. You will then need to use VB to aggregate it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee240819.aspx for lookupset, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/609759d2-15e4-4837-86dd-30bb420db116/sum-array-values-returned-by-lookupset-ssrs-2008-r2 to sum it.

Comment: This is a slower and clunkier way though, significantly worse than the original suggested.

Comment: @BishNaboB Believe me, if I could have done it in the query, this question wouldn't exist. And if I needed help writing the query, this question would have different tags.  Your solution with LookupSet works; do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: @angus Done and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a query to return a list of all potential colours. Make your tablix link to that dataset, and group by the colour column. You can then do a lookupset() along the lines of lookupset(Colour, Colour, ThingToSummarise, "Dataset"). This will return an array/object of all the rows where the colours match. You will then need to use VB to aggregate it. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/609759d2-15e4-4837-86dd-30bb420db116/sum-array-values-returned-by-lookupset-ssrs-2008-r2 to sum it.